# Passing a styled component as a child to another component throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to create a generic layout component that can have other components passed to it. However, when I pass in other styled components, I receive the error, "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, attrs, componentStyle, displayName, foldedComponentIds, styledComponentId, target, withComponent, warnTooManyClasses, toString}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

This is my layout component

```
const LayoutOne = props => {
    const {
        backgroundColors,
        navbar: navbarChildren,
        sideNavLeft,
        sideNavRight,
        subGridChildren
    } = props;
    return (
        <Grid bg={backgroundColors}>
            <Navbar bg={backgroundColors}>{navbarChildren}</Navbar>
            <SideNav bg={backgroundColors}>{sideNavLeft}</SideNav>
            <Subgrid bg={backgroundColors}>
                {subGridChildren.map(child => (
                    <SubgridRow bg={backgroundColors}>{child}</SubgridRow>
                ))}
            </Subgrid>
            <SideNav bg={backgroundColors}>{sideNavRight}</SideNav>
        </Grid>
    );
};
```

This is how I am instantiating it:

```
<LayoutOne
    navbar={Navbar}
    subGridChildren={[Name, SocialIconContainer, Slider]}
    sideNavLeft={PreviousBackground}
    sideNavRight={NextBackground}
/>
```

I have tried passing a styled div with no styles:

```
const Navbar = styled.div``;
```

And also other components with styles.

```
const Name = styled.h1`
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Monoton", cursive;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: calc(1em + 6vw);
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) to render and a component [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) substitute it with a call to [createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement). React knows how to render elements, strings, numbers, but not how to render objects.

In your case: ``` const Navbar = styled.div``; ```, `Navbar` is a function, that in turns is an object. So you are not sending to React something that it knows how to render. If you want it to work you have to send it an element:

```js
<LayoutOne
    navbar={<Navbar >}
    ...
/>
```